# Execute PL/SQL script block in C#

Tags: oracle-10g

I am trying to execute a PL/Sql block by using the OracleClientProvider in .Net . The language  I am using is c#, the DB is oracle10g

What I am actually doing is the following :

```
  //ConnectionSting is the connection String
  OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
  cmd.Connection = connection;

  // Open the connection
  connection.Open();

  //queryFile contains the PL/SQL Script I am trying to execute;
  String queryFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MasterDbScript"];
  String dataInFile = new StreamReader(queryFile).ReadToEnd();
  cmd.CommandText = dataInFile;

  connection.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
  //close the connection
  connection.close();
```

The PL/SQL block executes properly when I run it through ORACLE client but over here it throws an error ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

I want to ask :
1. Are the scripts executed in a different way from the normal query?
2. What am I doing wrong ?

Suggestions/Answers

Thanks.

Comment: What's the usefulness of the StreamReader injection? That shouldn't matter, you're trying to convert a string to a string :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not showing your script to us, lets work the other way around. 
create a table in your database

```
Create table Test_call_count (
count number(10)
);
insert into Test_call_count values (0);
```

and put the following into your script file

```
update  Test_call_count set count = count + 1;
```

After executing your code, you can check if it worked by selecting from the database.

The next step will be to use some begin end; block not returning any result sets.

Generally Ado can't process whole scripts. Using sql-server it can process batches, that are parts of a script separated by go statements. As far as I know for Oracle it can only process a single sql-statements or a begin end block.

Edit:
Here is a litte PowerShell you can use to try what is possible:

```
if ($ora_loaded -eq $null)
{
    $ora_loaded = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Oracle.DataAccess") 
}



$ConnectionString = "Data Source=YOUR_TNS;User ID=YOUR_ID;Password=YOUR_Password" 

function Execute-Query
{
    param (
        $sql
    )

        $conn = new-object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection 
        $conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString 
        $cmd = new-object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql,$conn)
    #   $cmd.CommandTimeout=$timeout
        $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
        $da = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($cmd)
        $nuLL = $da.fill($ds)
        $ds.tables[0]
        Write-Host ''
}

function Execute-NonQuery
{
    param (
        $sql
    )

        $conn = new-object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection 
        $conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString 
        $cmd = new-object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql,$conn)
        $conn.open()
    #   $cmd.CommandTimeout=$timeout
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $conn.close()
}

Execute-Query "select * from Test_call_count;"
Execute-NonQuery "update  Test_call_count set count = count + 1"
Execute-NonQuery "begin update  Test_call_count set count = count + 1; end;"
```

For example you see, that the following fails ( I added a semicolon):

```
Execute-NonQuery "update  Test_call_count set count = count + 1;"
```

And this fails too:

```
Execute-NonQuery "begin update  Test_call_count set count = count + 1; end;
/"
```

In a first approximation you can think of the '/' as similar to the sql-server batch delimiter go.

Answer (score 3):

From my limited understanding, blocks should be embedded in the C# or put in a package and called.  I've seen it like this:

```
@"
BEGIN
   SchemaName.PackageName.ProcedureName(p_LoginID => :loginID, 
      p_Password => :password, p_IPAddr => :ipAddr)";
END;”.Replace(Environment.NewLine, “\n”);
```

Comment: Replace(Environment.NewLine, “\n”) is a good idea